# Twitter4j search get only few fields

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Twitter4j search returns results with many fields.

ex:

```
StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Fri Jan 09 19:56:31 IST 2015, id=553558441482924033, text='Avast Free Antivirus 2015 [Download]: Avast Free Antivirus 2015 [Download] by AVAST Software s.r.o. Platform:… http://t.co/0zLPutC1PU', source='<a href="http://dlvr.it" rel="nofollow">dlvr.it</a>', isTruncated=false, inReplyToStatusId=-1, inReplyToUserId=-1, isFavorited=false, isRetweeted=false, favoriteCount=0, inReplyToScreenName='null', geoLocation=null, place=null, retweetCount=0, isPossiblySensitive=false, isoLanguageCode='en', lang='en', contributorsIDs=[], retweetedStatus=null, userMentionEntities=[], urlEntities=[URLEntityJSONImpl{url='http://t.co/0zLPutC1PU', expandedURL='http://amzn.to/1q69X9Z', displayURL='amzn.to/1q69X9Z'}], hashtagEntities=[], mediaEntities=[], symbolEntities=[], currentUserRetweetId=-1, user=UserJSONImpl{id=2792966010, name='Jessica', screenName='JessicaN372', location='US', description='Jessica', isContributorsEnabled=false, profileImageUrl='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/508946722307846144/E5Bi70E8_normal.jpeg', profileImageUrlHttps='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/508946722307846144/E5Bi70E8_normal.jpeg', url='null', isProtected=false, followersCount=128, status=null, profileBackgroundColor='C0DEED', profileTextColor='333333', profileLinkColor='0084B4', profileSidebarFillColor='DDEEF6', profileSidebarBorderColor='C0DEED', profileUseBackgroundImage=true, showAllInlineMedia=false, friendsCount=0, createdAt=Sat Sep 06 08:13:33 IST 2014, favouritesCount=0, utcOffset=-1, timeZone='null', profileBackgroundImageUrl='http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps='https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profileBackgroundTiled=false, lang='en', statusesCount=148653, isGeoEnabled=false, isVerified=false, translator=false, listedCount=2, isFollowRequestSent=false}}
```

Where I only require text and links.

How to request only certain fields

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to request certain fields as the Twitter Search API doesn't provide this functionality.

Instead you will need to extract what you are interested in from the `Status` yourself.

In your case you can use [`status.getText()`](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.0/twitter4j/Status.html#getText--) and [`status.getUrlEntities()`](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.0/twitter4j/EntitySupport.html#getURLEntities--) to get what you want.